# How can I get cocos2d to detect touches in non-standard rectangular shapes?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have been spending a lot of time googling around, finding lots of different answers to this question-- most of them are very old..  I tried a couple-- this one in particular (the first answer with the containsPoint / containsTouch category methods):
[how to detect touch on rotated sprite in cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634330/how-to-detect-touch-on-rotated-sprite-in-cocos2d)

When I implemented it, it incorrectly detected touches on sprites when I was far away from them-- and on top of that I got many warnings like "openGLView is deprecated".

Next, I came across this post:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1420

and checked out the touchesTest project...  Added the "CCTargetedTouchDelegate" protocol to my header, and then added the relevant implementation methods (onEnter, onExit, containsTouchLocation, and ccTouchBegan)...  And found that this is just not working because the sprites I am using are not rectangles...

My buttons look somewhat similar to this:
http://iphone.appstorm.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/ipconvert-1.jpg

rectangles that are rotated and get more narrow as they go down..

Any help with this would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used CGPathRef and worked also. [Here is one other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477909/cocos2d-iphone-non-rectangular-sprite-touch-detection) similar to ur question. Refer that for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement simple algorythm to detect if point is inside polygon. Point in this case will be your touch location, and polygon will be your button circuit.

Or you can make a bit more complex thing. You can create you own menu and your own buttons. It will allow you to create method like `containsPoint:` that will check if pixel at given position has zero alpha value or not.